# Running pt-table-checksum with replicate-do-db option on

Tags: mysql, replication, percona, percona-tools

I've read the documentation on percona page, but still a bit confused, especially about the **`--replicate`** option.

My setting is that the slave is only replicating certain databases from master, say `db1` and `db2`. So I have this following line in the `my.cnf` file on slave host:

```
replicate-do-db=db1
replicate-do-db=db2
```

So when I use the tool, I know I need to pass **`--databases=db1, db2`** as an option, but do I need to write the resulting checksum table into one of these dbs with **`--replicate=db1.checksum`**? I know by default it creates a database called `percona` and writes to **`percona.checksum`**, but since I'm not replicating all the databases, will it also create and write such a db on slave?

And after using the tool, should I be running **`USE db1`** before dropping the checksum table on master so that this is logged and sent to slave?

I know this can be easily tested but when I read the documentation mentioning of causing replication failure scared me. I somehow screwed my local MySQL and only having access to this two servers. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But do I need to write the resulting checksum table into one of these dbs with --replicate=db1.checksum?

Yes, you need. Otherwise it would not be replicated.

> And after using the tool, should I be running USE db1 before dropping the checksum table on master so that this is logged and sent to slave?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to make it run but appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Sveta's answer, you'll also need to set the flag --no-check-replication-filters so the tool won't complain about them.

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-checksum.html#cmdoption-pt-table-checksum--[no]check-replication-filters

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to make it run but appreciate your input.